# How do I use an image that was uploaded with mullter on mongodb in my react component?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, multer

So I uploaded an image on mongodb and now I want to use it in my react component but the file's path never seems to work:

```
router.post('/upload-avatar', upload.single('avatar'), uploadAvatar);


export default () => {
    const [imageSource, setImageSource] = React.useState('');
    const [imageAlt, setImageAlt] = React.useState('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/get-avatar`)
            .then(res => {
                setImageSource(res.data.posts[0].avatar.filePath.split('\\').join('\/'));
                setImageAlt(res.data.posts[0].avatar.fileName);
            })
    }, []);



    console.log(imageSource);

    return (
        <div className="avatar">
            <img src={imageSource} alt={imageAlt} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

In my component I only get that image placeholder, like when the image is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `uploadAvatar` must be:

For example:

```
(req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    const user = new User({
        ...
        profileImg: url + '/public/' + req.file.filename
        ...
 });
```

and response in react:

```
...
"user": {
  ...
  profileImg: "http://localhost:8000/public/avatar.png"
  ...
}
...
```

response should be url also express server should be is running (For example):

```
"profileImg": "http://localhost:8000/public/avatar.png"
```

If you save path of file uploaded in `db` without `url` in reactjs app:

change:

```
<img src={imageSource} alt={imageAlt} />
```

to

```
<img src=`http://localhost:8000/public/${imageSource}` alt={imageAlt} />
```

**You can use this article to get inspired:**

[React Single File Upload Tutorial with Node, Express and Multer](https://www.positronx.io/react-file-upload-tutorial-with-node-express-and-multer/)

Comment: thank you for your response. I have followed the steps you sugested and the article but I still get  GET http://localhost:8080/uploads/502-dem.jpg 404 (Not Found) error

Comment: Do you define static files directory in express? `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: I think I did but in the meanwhile I tweaked some things and now I messed everything up, I have to start from scratch. I am going to make a codesandbox.

Comment: So I have done that tutorial exactly as it is and everything works fine with saving to the database and all, except when it comes to specifying the file path as the image source in react. It just doesn't work.

Comment: The path saved on mongodb is  http://localhost:8080/public/705-irina.jpg and my file is in the same locaton, at the root of the project in the public folder. As in the image above, except the folder is called uploads.

Comment: Do you check this `localhost:8080/public/705-irina.jpg` in the browser. Was shown? Remember, The server must be running

Comment: Server is working, front and back. In the browser I get Cannot GET /public/705-irina.jpg

Comment: I have managed to make everithing work perfect by saving the image to mongodb as buffer, but I really want to make this work, by using the image path sa I dont have to save images to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out eventually. I cant just do:

```
<img src={imageSource} alt={imageAlt} />
```

cause it will never work for who knows what reason. But if instead I import the image from the folder to which multer saves the images, like so:

```
import someImage from './whatever/folder/multer/save/image/some-image.jpg'
```

it will work. I would have loved it to work the other way where I can pass the path from the http response directly to the image source attribute.